# Kind of OnChange for TControlScrollbar needed

Tags: delphi

I need help with standard scrollbar (of TControllScrollbar class) on a form. This kind of scrollbars has no OnChange event available but I need to intercept it somehow or related Windows message. Do you have any idea how to do that? 
Just to inform that message handlers for WM_VSCROLL or WM_HSCROLL messages don't work for me since these are fired only upon manual scrolling (like OnScroll event). In my case scrolling is performed by code, not manually.

Comment: From a quick view in the Delphi XE3's source I would say that your chances are quite small. [`TControlScrollBar.Position`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Forms.TControlScrollBar.Position) setter (if you're using it for that manual scrolling) calls [`FlatSB_SetScrollPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775437(v=vs.85).aspx) function which doesn't seem to care about `WM_*SCROLL` notifications.

Comment: If scrolling is preformed by your code couldn't that code also generate some event for you to use

Comment: Why are you using TControlScrollbar? TScrollbar is with much more functionality imho

Comment: @LHristov, `TControlScrollbar` is used internally by `TScrollingWinControl` class. So, control like e.g. `TScrollBox`, `TForm` or `TFrame` use it for their scroll bars. And the problem is that none of those controls have an `OnScroll` event.